# Plotting multiple model costs

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have created 3 models: sequential, conv and mix. I know how to plot each one by itself

```py
# Plots the training and validation loss over the number of epochs.
plt.plot(history.history['loss'])
plt.plot(history.history['val_loss'])
plt.title('Model Loss')
plt.ylabel('Loss')
plt.xlabel('Epoch')
plt.legend(['Train', 'Validation'], loc='upper right')
plt.show()

history1 = model.fit(
    data_generator.flow(train_x, to_categorical(train_y), batch_size=BATCH_SIZE), 
    steps_per_epoch=len(train_x) / BATCH_SIZE,
    validation_data=data_generator.flow(val_x, to_categorical(val_y), batch_size=BATCH_SIZE),
    validation_steps=len(val_x) / BATCH_SIZE,
    epochs=NUM_EPOCHS
)
```

My problem is with the history part as they all share the same history and I can't change it. Even if I change it  to `history1` it's embedded in Keras. It gives me the following error: `History object has no attribute 'history1'`
Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `history1.history`. history1 is the name of your variable and history is the name of its attribute.

From the model.fit keras documentation:

> Returns:
> A History object. Its History.history attribute is a record of training loss values and metrics values at successive epochs, as well as validation loss values and validation metrics values (if applicable).

Comment: Thanks a lot. You saved me hours :)